# Big Sur opens Gmail in Chrome instead of Mail app for mail links

Tags: email-client, macos-bigsur

Ever since upgrading to Big Sur, mail links in my address book open Gmail in a Chrome browser.

The default mail account is set to an iCloud account, and still Gmail opens. Before upgrading, it opened my default mail program (Apple Mail in the pre-Big Sur era).

Are there any other prefs to disable this annoying behaviour?

Besides that, MS Excel (on Mac) shows a PDF in Chrome after clicking "Share as PDF...".

Comment: Does [this post](https://support.apple.com/en-mz/HT201607) help?

Comment: No, default mail reader is set to the mail app, still it opens Gmail in a chrome browser

Comment: Looks like Chrome has appropriated the `message:` scheme. If you still have this issue, could you launch Terminal and post the output of: `alias lsregister='/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister'` and `lsregister -dump | sed -n 'H; /^claimed schemes:.* message:/{p; g; s/.*\n\(path:.*\)\ndirectory:.*/\1/; p;}; /\n-----/{s/.*//; x;};'`? The first command creates an alias to `lsregister`, the second looks for apps that have registered `message:` in the Launch Services database. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the update to Big Sur didn't update the mail handlers.

To resolve, i had to register gmail (chrome) as a mail handler.
After doing so, gmail showed up as the default mail application. With both gmail and mail.app showing in the list, i was able to switch it to mail.app.